# Unable to connect through browser window

Tags: google-compute-engine

I deleted the firewall rule `default-allow-ssh` and now I cannot SSH via browser window even after adding back the same rule:

[image]

I have gone through the check list [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror), but still can't figure out the cause. The problem is happening to existing instances as well as a newly created Ubuntu f1.micro instance which has all the Google defaults.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default-ssh-allow firewall rule must have tcp:22 as authorized port.

It seems you just set 22, without specifying the protocol. that's certainly the reason.

Comment: NB: I think this question should be posted in ServerFault instead of Stack Overflow. It will probably be flagged soon. Please consult this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic